Data is being delayed when conditional fetching in next js

type AuthContextType = {
  user: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
  subscription: Subscription | null; // Add this
  isSubscriptionCheckComplete: boolean; // Add this
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  subscription: null,
  isSubscriptionCheckComplete: false,
});

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState<Subscription | null>(null);
  const setUseMockData = useSetRecoilState(useMockDataState);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isSubscriptionCheckComplete, setSubscriptionCheckComplete] =
    useState(false);

  // Fetch subscription data when user changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      setSubscription(null);
      setSubscriptionCheckComplete(true);
      return undefined; // Ensure we clean up when the user logs out or is not set
    }

    const subscriptionReference = query(
      subscriptionRef(user.uid),
      orderBy('created', 'desc'),
      limit(1)
    );

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      subscriptionReference,
      (snapshot) => {
        setSubscription(snapshot.empty ? null : snapshot.docs[0].data());
        setSubscriptionCheckComplete(true);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching subscription:', error);
        setSubscriptionCheckComplete(true);
      }
    );

    return unsubscribe; // Clean up subscription on component unmount or user change
  }, [user]);

  // Adjust mock data usage based on subscription status
  useEffect(() => {
    const hasSubscription = ['active', 'trialing'].includes(
      subscription?.status ?? ''
    );
    setUseMockData(!hasSubscription);
    setSubscriptionCheckComplete(true);
  }, [isSubscriptionCheckComplete, subscription, setUseMockData]);

  // Handle authentication state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe(); // Clean up on component unmount
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, subscription, loading, isSubscriptionCheckComplete }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};


export type Review = {
  id: string;
  stars: number;
  comments: string;
  submittedAt: string;
  recommended: boolean;
  feedbackOptions: string[];
};

const useReviews = () => {
 
const [reviews, setReviews] = useState<Review[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Initialize loading to true
  const {
    user,
    loading: userLoading,
    isSubscriptionCheckComplete,
  } = useAuthContext();
  const useMockData = useRecoilValue(useMockDataState);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Immediately return if the user data is still loading
    const fetchReviews = async () => {
      if (!isSubscriptionCheckComplete || userLoading || !user) {
        return;
      }
      setLoading(true); // Ensure loading state is true at the start of data fetching
      try {
        if (!useMockData && user?.uid) {
          // Fetch live data if mock data is not used and user is logged in
          const reviewsRef = collection(db, `users/${user.uid}/reviews`);
          const q = query(reviewsRef);
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
          const liveReviews: Review[] = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            let formattedDate = '';
            if (
              data.submittedAt &&
              typeof data.submittedAt.toDate === 'function'
            ) {
              formattedDate = format(data.submittedAt.toDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            }
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              stars: data.stars,
              comments: data.comments,
              submittedAt: formattedDate,
              recommended: data.recommended,
              feedbackOptions: data.feedbackOptions || [],
            };
          });
          setReviews(liveReviews);
        } else {
          // Use mock data if the conditions are met
          setReviews([...mockReviews2022_24]);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error);
        setReviews([]); // Set reviews to an empty array in case of an error
      } finally {
        setLoading(false); // Ensure loading state is false after data is fetched
      }
    };

    fetchReviews();
  }, [useMockData, userLoading, user, isSubscriptionCheckComplete]);

  return { reviews, loading };
};
export default useReviews;

Im trying to check whether or not to display mockdata or live data to a user based on their subscription. However there seems to be a delay in fetching.
1st the mockdata shows then the loading shows based on const {loading} = useReviews
2nd the live data shows.
I want the loading to show only in my compoenents where im using the hook.
In my component im doing if (loading) {Loading..} return
The inital flicker wont seem to go away.
